# Confused where to look for that < symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, syntax-error, symbols

i have a code but i cannot figure out why it gives me an error of:

```
    Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '<'
```

and this is the snippet

```
    $pattern = "/<tr.*?data-eventid=\"(\d+)\"/" .               // id
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}.*\s(.*?)<div.*/?>\s(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}" .     // Day and Date
    "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}" .                               // Time
    "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}" .                               // Currency
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}<div.*?>(.*?)<\/div>\s{0,}<\/td>\s{0,}" .    // Impact
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}<div.*?>(.*?)<\/div>\s{0,}<\/td>\s{0,}" .    // Indicator
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}<div.*?>(.*?)<\/div>\s{0,}<\/td>\s{0,}" .    // Detail
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}(.*?)\s{0,}<\/td>\s{0,}" .                   // Actual
    "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}" .                               // Forecast
    "<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}".                                // Previous
    "<td.*?>\s{0,}<div.*?>(.*?)<\/div>\s{0,}<\/td>\s{0,}/ims"; // Chart 忽略
```

i am so confused where to look for that < symbol..

Best Regards

Comment: You're not escaping a `/` somewhere actually.

Comment: `<tr` in first line, where is `>`?

Comment: Just throw it away. That's insane to parse HTML with RegExp, use DOM component.

Comment: The entire regular expression is just wrong. No matter which way you swing it. Please stop trying to parse HTML with regular expressions and learn to use an HTML parser [DOMDocument](http://php.net/dom). Just like you use a screw driver to screw a screw and a hammer to hammer a nail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, seriously, wow. That's not a regular expression I'd throw at my worst enemy.

```
"/<tr.*?data-eventid=\"(\d+)\"/"
                              ^

"<td.*?>\s{0,}.*\s(.*?)<div.*/?>\s(.*?)<\/td>\s{0,}"
                             ^
```

Those need to be escaped because they're used as the delimiter. Not escaping them will make `preg` think the expression is over and trailing characters will be treated as modifiers.

You should really look into a proper HTML parser though, this is madness!

See also: [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/domdocument)

Comment: im sorry..new to this:| but by the way..i lot of thanks..

Answer (score 1):

First line:
`$pattern = "/<tr.*?data-eventid=\"(\d+)\"/" .`

should be

`$pattern = "/<tr.*?data-eventid=\"(\d+)\"\/" .`